# SendingSimpleGoals tutorial: CMaker error

Tags: ros, move-base-msgs, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to do [Sending simple goal tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals). I did

```
catkin_create_pkg simple_navigation_goals move_base_msgs actionlib roscpp
```

I didn't do anything else (because I'm checking this tutorial only to learn how to include costmap_2d that I was trying to do but i couldn't manage  to complete) so I did

```
catkin_make
```

but there is an error

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package move_base_msgs.
```

there is some explanation how to fix it under an error

```
Set move_base_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration
file for move_base_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:

  move_base_msgsConfig.cmake
  move_base_msgs-config.cmake
```

why I have to set sth, shouldn't it work? Do i have some system variables wrong or sth?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/145176/sendingsimplegoals-tutorial:-cmaker-error/) by [BP](https://answers.ros.org/users/10951/bp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 176 on 2014-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you are running ROS Groovy.
There, move_base_msgs is not catkinized yet and thus cannot be find_packaged.
This is due to the fact that you cannot have dependencies from a catking pkg to a rosbuild pkg.

Either update to hydro or try the tutorial with rosbuild.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2014-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BP](https://answers.ros.org/users/10951/bp/) on 2014-03-27**:
So there is no walk around, right?